# Visibility of buildnumber-maven-plugin property ${buildNumber}

Tags: maven, maven-tomcat-plugin, buildnumber-maven-plugin

I am trying to use [`buildnumber-maven-plugin`](http://www.mojohaus.org/buildnumber-maven-plugin) to append the SCM build number to the WAR artifact name and then use [`tomcat7-maven-plugin`](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.0/tomcat7-maven-plugin/plugin-info.html) to deploy it but in a context path that doesn't include the build number. So I am making **foo-r1234.war** where foo is my project and 1234 is the revision number in Subversion but I want to deploy it in a Tomcat context **foo**.

I got the war generation to reflect the build number but the problem is that the Tomcat plugin doesn't see the `${buildNumber}` property assigned by the buildnumber plugin:

```
<finalName>foo-r${buildNumber}</finalName>
...
<plugin>
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.4</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>create-buildno</id>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>create</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <doCheck>false</doCheck>
        <doUpdate>false</doUpdate>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
...
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
        <path>/foo</path>
    <warFile>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.war</warFile>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I get

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:deploy (default-cli) on project foo: Cannot find war file: /my/path/target/foo-r${buildNumber}.war -> [Help 1]
>   [ERROR]

Which indicates the tomcat plugin doesn't see ${buildNumber}. How can I make it visible in order to deploy foo-r${buildNumber}.war to a context foo in Tomcat?

<sub>**RELATED:**</sub>

[How to deploy war with automatic buildnumber to tomcat using maven tomcat plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18523033/how-to-deploy-war-with-automatic-buildnumber-to-tomcat-using-maven-tomcat-plugin)

[timestamp and buildNumber properties not set during deploy goal](https://github.com/mojohaus/buildnumber-maven-plugin/issues/58)

Answer (score 0):

Add build final name in configuration 
    
        /${project.build.finalName}